# Почему не работает прослушивание клавиш SHIFT и delete? js

Tags: javascript

```js
function login() {
    let email = document.getElementById('emailid').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if (email == 'пациент' && password == '123456') {
        location.assign('http://127.0.0.1:5500/wellcome_page.html')
    }
    else {
        window.alert('Доступ ЗАПРЕЩЕН')
    }
}
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')


const backspace_btn = document.querySelector('.backspace')
const shift_btn = document.querySelector('.shift')
const space_btn = document.querySelector('.space')

let chars = []

buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputs.forEach(input => {
            if (input.classList.contains('active')) {
                input.value += btn.innerText
                chars = input.value.split("")
                console.log(chars);
            }
        });
    });
});

inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
        inputs.forEach(input => {
            input.classList.remove('active');
        });
        input.classList.add('active');
    });
});




    backspace_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chars.pop()
        inputs.value = chars.join('')
    })
    space_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chars.push('_')
        inputs.value = chars.join('')
    })
    shift_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        buttons.forEach(btn => {
            btn.classList.toggle('upper')
        })
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>КЛАВИАТУРА</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-login">
        <h2>РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ</h2>
        <label for="inputName">Электронный ящик :</label>
        <br><br>
        <input class="input-one" type="email" id="emailid" name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
        <br><br>
        <label for="inputPassword">ПАРОЛЬ :</label>
        <br><br>
        <input class="input-two" type="password" id="password" name="pass" placeholder="Ваш пароль" required>
        <br><br><br>    
        <button class="login-btn" onclick="login()">ВОЙТИ</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-kayboard">
      
            <!-- КЛАВИАТУРА НАЧАЛО -->
            <div id="virtual-keyboard">
                <div class="line one">
                    <button class="btn">Ё</button>
                    <button class="btn">1</button>
                    <button class="btn">2</button>
                    <button class="btn">3</button>
                    <button class="btn">4</button>
                    <button class="btn">5</button>
                    <button class="btn">6</button>
                    <button class="btn">7</button>
                    <button class="btn">8</button>
                    <button class="btn">9</button>
                    <button class="btn">0</button>
                    <button class="btn">-</button>
                    <button class="btn">=</button>
                    <button class="backspace">Backspace</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="line two">
                <button class="tab">Tab</button>
                <button class="btn">Й</button>
                <button class="btn">Ц</button>
                <button class="btn">У</button>
                <button class="btn">К</button>
                <button class="btn">Е</button>
                <button class="btn">Н</button>
                <button class="btn">Г</button>
                <button class="btn">Ш</button>
                <button class="btn">Щ</button>
                <button class="btn">З</button>
                <button class="btn">Х</button>
                <button class="btn">Ъ</button>
                <button class="slice">/</button>
            </div>
            <div class="line three">
                <button class="caps">CapsLock</button>
                <button class="btn">Ф</button>
                <button class="btn">Ы</button>
                <button class="btn">В</button>
                <button class="btn">А</button>
                <button class="btn">П</button>
                <button class="btn">Р</button>
                <button class="btn">О</button>
                <button class="btn">Л</button>
                <button class="btn">Д</button>
                <button class="btn">Ж</button>
                <button class="btn">Э</button>
                <button class="enter-btn">ENTER</button>
            </div>
            <div class="line four">
                <button class="shift">SHIFT</button>
                <button class="btn">Я</button>
                <button class="btn">Ч</button>
                <button class="btn">С</button>
                <button class="btn">М</button>
                <button class="btn">И</button>
                <button class="btn">Т</button>
                <button class="btn">Ь</button>
                <button class="btn">Б</button>
                <button class="btn">Ю</button>
                <button class="btn">.</button>
                <button class="btn">,</button>
                <button class="shift">SHIFT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="line five">
                <button class="other">Ctrl</button>
                <button class="other">Alt</button>
                <button class="space">SPACE</button>
                <button class="other">Alt</button>
                <button class="other">Ctrl</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- КЛАВИАТУРА ОКОНЧАНИЕ -->

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `shift` работает только один, потому что там две кнопки `shift` а лиснер Вы вешаете только на одну, `delete` кнопки как таковой у Вас нет, если это `backspace` то законсольте, клик у Вас отслеживается.